# Stadium game at Miami blocking runways?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, notam

So I was looking for the Miami In in SkyVector and I saw this.

Apparently a stadium game has the power to block runways in (At least in US).

What is really going on there? I am not well acquinted with charts.

[image: Not My PC]

Comment: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/18770/43

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blanket NOTAM includes this language:

> UNLESS THE AIRCRAFT OPERATOR MEETS AT LEAST ONE OF THE FOLLOWING REQUIREMENTS: A) THE AIRCRAFT OPERATION HAS BEEN AUTHORIZED BY ATC FOR OPERATIONAL OR SAFETY PURPOSES, INCLUDING AUTHORIZATION OF FLIGHTS SPECIFICALLY ARRIVING AT OR DEPARTING FROM AN AIRPORT DESIGNATED BY ATC USING STANDARD ATC PROCEDURES AND ROUTES

Answer (score 2):

It is a temporary restriction, not a prohibition.  If you are departing or approaching an airport within a TFR for a sporting event, ATC will assign you a squawk that will clear you through the airspace.  I have done this several times at KBFI while games are going on.  They just don't want enroute traffic trundling through, and they ask that you do not overfly the stadiums.